# Angular 4 : How to assign array of string into checkbox in reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying display checkboxes for my user roles:

For eg. I have two user roles : 1.Admin 2.Employee

I have an array of roles in userObject:

```
user={
    "name":"Bhushan",
    "email":"bhushan@yaho.com",
    "roles":['Admin','Employee']
}
```

I want to use reactive form to populate this model into form. I want to populate the roles array into read-only checkboxes i.e. when form loads, user can edit name & email but checkboxes will show `admin` toggeled if user has admin role or untoggled if he is not an admin. same can be said for employee role.

So far I have tried following:

```
<form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <div style="margin-bottom: 1em">
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="userForm.pristine" class="btn btn-success">Save</button> &nbsp;
    <button type="reset" (click)="revert()" [disabled]="userForm.pristine" class="btn btn-danger">Revert</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Name:
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Email:
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="email">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let role of roles;let i=index">
    <label>
        // I tried this, but it doesn't work
        <!--<input type="checkbox" [name]="role" [(ngModel)]="role">-->
       {{role}}
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

<p>userForm value: {{ userForm.value | json}}</p>`
```

Any Inputs?

Comment: So user can have both roles `Admin` and `Employee` at the same time? Just looking at the array you presented, both are present in the array and not stated which role that user has.

Comment: have you tried using the `patchValue` method of reactive form ?

Comment: @AJT_82 yes. user can be admin and employee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps do something like the following. Build your form, and stick the roles in a form array:

```
this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  name: [this.user.name],
  roles: this.fb.array(this.user.roles || [])
});

// OPTIONAL: put the different controls in variables
this.nameCtrl = this.userForm.controls.name;
this.rolesCtrl = this.userForm.controls.roles.controls;
```

and the roles array you are iterating in the template could look like this:

```
roles = ['Admin', 'Employee','Some role 1', 'Some role 2']
```

and in your iteration just compare and set the `role` in `roles` array as checked in case it matches a value in the form array. Use safe navigation operator, as we know that the `roles` array is probably longer that the form array, so that an error won't be thrown trying to read an index that doesn't exist:

```html
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let role of roles;let i=index">
  <input [checked]="role == rolesCtrl[i]?.value" 
     [disabled]="true" type="checkbox">{{role}}
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UKBY7tKoNAGs6kt7QF9B?p=preview)**